# How to insert values into Postgresql column with datatype as double precision

Tags: postgresql, insert, precision

When I am trying to insert a date with timestamp to my postgresql table, I am getting the below error:

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type double precision: "2011-05-31 02:20:30"
```

The query is below. Here the ID field is a text and the REPORTED_DATE field is a double precision.

```
insert into my_table ("ID", "REPORTED_DATE")  values('ID8033','2011-05-31 02:20:30');
```

How do I need to change the query to be able to insert it ? Or do I need to change the datatype of the REPORTED_FIELD column accordingly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the datatype of REPORTED_FIELD, use timestamp, or change the string to get the time (seconds, milliseconds) of date and change the field to integer.

Comment: thanks, it worked. I could solve it as :alter table my_table alter column "REPORTED_DATE" type timestamp with time zone using to_timestamp('REPORTED_DATE', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');

Answer (score 0):

`double precision` is a floating-point number: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype.html.

You are looking for `timestamp`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-datetime.html